# How can change the first submenu name of a menu in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

[image]

I have created a menu in wordpress dashboard using add_menu_page and a submenu under that parent menu. The green marked name came auto. I want to change it to something like All CSV. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

change like this

```
add_menu_page("my-plugin", "Main Menu", "publish_posts", "activate_plugin", "wpqs_active_plugin");
add_submenu_page("activate_plugin", "Sub menu", "Activation", "publish_posts", "activate_plugin", "wpqs_active_plugin");
```